# How to import a variable from another script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I want to get a variable from another script, as demonstrated in  this question on Stack Overflow:

[How to reference a file for variables in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228345/bash-script-how-to-reference-a-file-for-variables)

However, the answer uses the `source` command which is only available in `bash`. I want to do this in a portable way.

I have also tried

**a.sh**

```
export VAR="foo"
echo "executing a"
```

**b.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
./a.sh
echo $VAR
```

But of course that does not work either. How to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First of all, be aware that `var` and `VAR` are different variables.

To answer your question the `.` command is not bash-specific:

```
# a.sh
num=42
```

```
# b.sh
. ./a.sh
echo $num
```

The variables in "a" do not need to be exported.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins

Comment: Thank you and excuse my typo. I was pretty surprised with the difference between `./a.sh` and `. ./a.sh`. Care to explain the difference?

Comment: The dot command (`.` or `source`) evaluates the script in your *current* shell. Executing the script first spawns a subshell, and any environment changes in the subshell are lost when the subshell exits -- a child process cannot alter the environment of its parent.

Comment: bash has a handy `help` builtin to access the manual for a specific command -- see `help .`

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are only inherited from parent to child and not the other way round. In your example, b.sh calls a.sh, so a runs as a child of b. When a.sh exports var, it won't be seen by b.sh. Amend the logic so that the *parent* process exports the variable, e.g.

**a.sh:**

```
echo In a.sh...
VAR="test"
export VAR
./b.sh
```

**b.sh:**

```
echo In b.sh...
echo $VAR
```

Comment: Thank you, but I actually have `sharedDefs.sh` and two separate targets depending on it, so I need to have the dependencies this way.